# What is a "bogle"?

Tags: the-island-of-doctor-moreau

In *The Island of Doctor Moreau*, when Prendick first sees the Beast Man, Montgomery tells him that it could be a "bogle":

> I stood up in front of him. "What was that thing that came after me?" I asked.
>   He looked me squarely in the eyes, and twisted his mouth askew. His eyes, which had seemed animated a minute before, went dull. "From your account," said he, "I’m thinking it was a bogle."
>   I felt a gust of intense irritation, which passed as quickly as it came. I flung myself into the chair again, and pressed my hands on my forehead. The puma began once more.
>   <sub>*The Island of Doctor Moreau*, chapter 10: "The Crying of the Man"</sub>

What is this "bogle", and why did Montgomery tell Predick that that's what it was?

Comment: Read that in French a long time ago, but IIRC Montgomery was talking about some kind of _mauvais esprit_ ("bad, evil spirit"), which seems confirmed by [the definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bogle). I don't remember if there was an in-universe explanation, though...

Comment: [Bogle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogle), although it immediately made me think of [Boggle Hole, Robin Hood's Bay, UK](http://www.northyorkmoors.org.uk/visiting/see-and-do/attractions/robin-hoods-bay).

Answer (score 8):

It's a spirit, a passing ghost, a wisp of air one's eye catches in fleeting moments.

> A bogle, boggle, or bogill is a Northumbrian and Scots term for a ghost or folkloric being... They are reputed to live for the simple purpose of perplexing mankind, rather than seriously harming or serving them.

[Definition.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogle)

Similar to American "bogey", like as in a UFO and also, relatedly but more malevolently, the "bogey-man".

---

Montgomery was gaslighting Prendick, insinuating he wasn't right in what he saw, that it was imagination and fancy. Thus Prendick's subsequent irritation, as Prendick was certain it was more than fancy. Montgomery, of course, had motive to downplay the event, not wanting Prendick to learn of the island's secrets (and Montgomery's genuine concern for the beast folk).

I'll speculate that the use of language here adds some nuance to Montgomery's character. We know Montgomery was in London society "before making an ass of himself" and leaving, but little else. Use of this regional term hints of recent Scottish ancestry in Montgomery, though Wells writes Montgomery's dialogue without a brogue, suggesting he was a man more of London society than his ancestry might imply.

Comment: Thanks for the definition - but what about the second half of the question? Why does Montgomery try to tell Prendick that this is what he saw was?

Comment: The book is available at Project Gutenberg, if you want to add quotes to your answer ([link](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/159/159-h/159-h.htm)). I'm particularly thinking of _But it's not so bad as you feel, man. Your nerves are worked to rags_, but I'm just putting that thought here and leaving you to decide what to do with it :)

Comment: In the movie Island of Lost Souls, the visitor to the island is told they are "natives" -- no one is very forthcoming about the true nature of the creatures.